# How to handle (possible) unwanted plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

Browsing some questions today I found one (it's a relative common problem) with 2 almost identical answers from `user A` and `user B`. Usually I ignore the similar answers because I believe it's possible that two different users give almost the same answer. Today however, I realised that some variables have very unique name to be given by two different users, so I decided to have a closer look. After a few minutes I was able to found the following:

- `user A` has 4 duplicate answers (3 of them should probably be removed);
- `user B` has 2 duplicate answers (probably copied from `user A` since he thanked user A for that answer).

Now comes the fun part: looking even closer I found another question from November 2012 answered by `user C` who has the same answer with that particular name for variables and another one from June 2012 from `user D`. I wasn't able to find nothing before 2012 so I believe that `user D` had the original answer. Based on what I read about plagiarism, I admit that the newer answers are based on the fourth, but I tend to believe that this behaviour might be somehow unwanted (excluding the clear duplicates) because the users in case might have tried themselves the last answer, change it to fit their needs and then reposted when a similar question was added. How would you handle a case like this when you find a history of almost identical answers?

Comment: plagiarism _in general_ is handled by mod flagging one of the plagiarized posts in question and explaining with all sources and other related posts...A moderator will take a look at the flag

Comment: Raise a custom moderator flag on any post explaining the whole situation.

Comment: To be honest, I don't believe that I can write the whole story in a single moderator flag because of the characters limit, but should be a starting point.

Comment: @IulianPopescu - I guess since you've written this meta post - in the flag you just need to refer to the users/posts and a link to here for further information... That should fit...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If this is referring to the cases you flagged yesterday, you were accurate in pointing out plagiarism from an original answer.

What appeared to have happened was that someone left an original answer that was a good solution to a core problem and was highly voted. This was a common problem, so duplicate or related questions were asked in several places. Multiple users independently plagiarized this source answer, some of them several times over. The users themselves weren't related, they were just independent plagiarists. The plagiarized answers were deleted and the users handled.

I'd probably recommend dealing with this case as you would any other instance of plagiarism: casting a custom moderator flag indicating the answer is plagiarized, with a link to the source material. We can see when a user has been flagged multiple times for plagiarism, so we can tell when there's a trend that needs to be dealt with. You could also provide a short statement that this was a pattern for a user, because that can't hurt.

Now, code does get reused in snippets that get passed on from example to example, so that does happen naturally. What set these cases apart was that they used the wording and formatting from the original answer in their plagiarized answers. That's how you know they were copied and not simply inspired by the original.

Comment: *"This was a common problem, so duplicate or related questions were asked in several places."* For me this is an issue. What's the line/threshold here? (1) If the problem is common and several "related" questions, what's the threshold for being a dup? (2) If the OP isn't a dup, then what was the threshold for the answer being plagiarism? (3) If the *answer* contained (a) a link to everything - attribution - and explained the "core" problem is handled in the linked question, is it still plagiarism? Or (4) should such a thing - attribution - be posted as a comment?

Comment: @dfd - I marked the questions as duplicate that clearly were asking the same thing. As for plagiarism, the answers referred to here copied the exact wording and even the nonstandard formatting of the original post, making it clear that they were copied and pasted. No citation was provided. If wording is properly blockquoted, stated to come from the original author, and linked to the original post, that would satisfy attribution requirements. However, I'd prefer that they add something on top of the quoted answer. If they're just going to link to another answer, that might be best as a comment.

Comment: Devil's advocate: This is a question-answer site. If the answer in question was actually the correct one for the scenario, isn't the fact that it was further promulgated a good thing? Or is the point just that they should have cited the original answer?

Comment: @Stephen - There are two problems: they are attempting to take credit for the work of others in order to benefit from it, and they are violating the attribution requirements of the site. Personally, I have real problems with people who try to claim the written work of others as their own. Organizationally, we want people to be funneled towards a single canonical question or answer for common problems, so that there's only place you need to turn (it's why SE was designed with the duplicate close reason). This avoids the common forum issue of solutions being scattered across multiple topics.

Comment: I'm curious what happened with the questions whose plagiarized answers got deleted. Asked more generally: if a plagiarized (but correct) answer gets deleted, but the question is not a duplicate (so it can not be closed and linked to the original question whose answer was plagiarized), does the question get left without an answer (assuming there are no other answers)? Or will mods attempt to salvage the answer with some editing and referencing?

Comment: @RToyota - It depends on the specific situation. Usually, there are other answers, so the question isn't left completely unanswered. In many cases, the questions are clear duplicates (the plagiarist did a simple search on the site and copied an answer from a question asking the same thing), so we can mark those as duplicates. Only in rare cases do we edit the answer to leave proper attribution, because that's the responsibility of the answerer, not the community. We do try to prevent the loss of information on deletion of one of these answers via duplicate links, comments, etc.

Comment: @BradLarson to continue my devil's advocacy, note that the "benefit" they are supposedly gaining for themselves is flimsy, just points in a gamified system. Maybe in some cases they just copied and pasted because they wanted to help somebody who had a problem, and couldn't be bothered to put in the extra work to "make it their own."